# Python Selenium Click on object inside specific row

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I have site and the HTML looks like this:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1">555</td>
    <td>
        <a href="/fruit_list/555">FruitType1 : Fruit1</a>
    </td>
    <td>Fruit1</td>
    <td>FruitType1</td>
    <td>Somwhere</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>
        <button class="copy_button btn_gray_inverse" id="555">Copy</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="fruit check_btn" id="555" href="" value="0">
            <i class="bt_check"></i>
        </button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="fruit remove_btn" id="555" href="#">
            <i class="bt_remove">
            ::before
            </i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Im trying to click on button (`<button class="fruit check_btn" id="555" href="" value="0">`) inside this specific row. Rows can be different only in text under tr (Fruit1, Fruit2), with this code and its not working:

```
FruitList = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath\
    ('//tr[@role="row" and contains (., "Fruit1")]')
for Fruit in FruitList:
    Enabled = Fruit.find_element_by_xpath('//i[@class="bt_check"]')
    Enabled.click()
```

It allways clicks on button from first awailable row on the page, not the one that is containing text "Fruit1".

Please help

Comment: Can you update the question with your exact `manual steps` which you are trying to Automate?

Comment: 1. Locating row which contains text "Fruit1" 2. Click on button that is located inside row from step 1

Comment: 1. What do you want to do after locating `the row which contains text "Fruit1"`? 2. Does this item `row containing text "Fruit1"` appears multiple times on the Web Page?

Comment: Nope, row containing "Fruit1" appears only once on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the check button for Fruit1, I suggest you to do it in two steps.

First find the row for Fruit1:

```
fruit_row = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='Fruit1']/..")
```

Note that I use /.. at the end of the Xpath in order to select the *tr* element that contains the *td* with text 'Fruit1' instead of the *td* himself.

Second step, find the button and click on it:

```
fruit_row.find_element_by_class_name("check_btn").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on `<td>` with text as **`Fruit1`**, you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td/a[contains(@href,'/fruit_list/555')]//following::td[text()='Fruit1']")
```

You can be more generic with :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td/a[contains(@href,'/fruit_list/555')]//following::td[1]")
```

Comment: Yea thanks, but still clicks button frm first row on page, not the one that contains text "Fruit1".

Comment: New on stack so need to be more careful on which answer i comment. Thank you :)

Comment: My Answer was in `Java` earlier which I have changed to `Python` now. Check it out.